# How do I use/download a sound correctly using node.js and play it through the client?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, audio

I use the command in the **server file**

```
app.use('/client',express.static(__dirname + '/client'));
```

and in the **client**, the file i'm trying to play is located

```
C:\Users\me\Desktop\project\client\sound.mp3
```

it is the right directory but how do I play it through the client?

Sorry if this is confusing I can clarify any questions.

Comment: use an audio element

Comment: Create an express route (static or manual) that serves the audio file.  Then specific an appropriate URL that will hit that route in an `<audio>` tag in your HTML page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by sending over my sound file through the server by using
app.get function
then using
res.sendFile(directoryOfFile) funtion through my server file